# Why does a column from pandas DataFrame not work in this loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I took from basketball-reference with player names. The code below is how I built the DataFrame. It has 5 columns of player names, but each name also has the player's position.

```
url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/all_league.html"
dframe_list = pd.io.html.read_html(url)
df = dframe_list[0]
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2]], inplace=True, axis=1)
column_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
df.columns = column_names
df = df[df.name1.notnull()]
```

I am trying to split off the position. To do so I had planned to make a DataFrame for each name column:

```
name1 = pd.DataFrame(df.name1.str.split().tolist()).ix[:,0:1]
name1[0] = name1[0] + " " + name1[1]
name1.drop(name1.columns[[1]], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Since I have five columns I thought I would do this with a loop

```
column_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
for column in column_names:
    column = pd.DataFrame(df.column.str.split().tolist()).ix[:,0:1]
    column[0] = column[0] + " " + column[1]
    column.drop(column.columns[[1]], inplace=True, axis=1)
    column.columns = column
```

And then I'd join all these DataFrames back together.

```
df_NBA = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5]
df_NBA = pd.concat(df_NBA, axis=1)
```

I'm new to python, so I'm sure I'm doing this in a pretty cumbersome fashion and would love suggestions as to how I might do this faster. But my main question is, when I run the code on individual columns it works fine, but if when I run the loop I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'
```

It seems that the part of the loop `df.column.str` is causing some problem? I've fiddled around with the list, with bracketing column (I still don't understand why sometimes I bracket a DataFrame column and sometimes it's .column, but that's a bigger issue) and other random things.

When I try @BrenBarn's suggestion

```
df.apply(lambda c: c.str[:-2])
```

The following pops up in the Jupyter notebook:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation:    http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Looking at the DataFrame, nothing has actually changed and if I understand the documentation correctly this method creates a copy of the DataFrame with the edits, but that this is a temporary copy that get's thrown out afterward so the actual DataFrame doesn't change.

Comment: Are you saying it also doesn't work if you do `df[column]`?

Comment: `df.column` corresponds to `df['column']`, not `df[column]`. So when column is a variable, you cannot use it like that.

Comment: @BrenBarn, yep, it doesn't work if I use `df[column]`, `df['column']`, I guess that's what @ayhan is saying. So is there an answer?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  If I run your code with `df[column]`, I do get errors, but they're related to resetting the column names (your `column.columns = column`).  Also, your data sample has only two columns but your code still tries to iterate over 5, leading to additional errors.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the actual DataFrame I am working with. Thanks @BrenBarn for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the position labels are always only one character, the simple solution is this:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda c: c.str[:-2])
           name1         name2
0     Marc Gasol  Lebron James
1      Pau Gasol  Kevin Durant
2  Dwight Howard  Kyrie Irving
```

The `str` attribute of a Series lets you do string operations, including indexing, so this just trims the last two characters off each value.

As for your question about `df.column`, this issue is more general than pandas.  These two things are not the same:

```
# works
obj.attr

# doesn't work
attrName = 'attr'
obj.attrName
```

You can't use the dot notation when you want to access an attribute whose name is stored in a variable.  In general, you can use the `getattr` function instead.  However, pandas provides the bracket notation for accessing a column by specifying the name as a *string* (rather than a source-code identifier).  So these two are equivalent:

```
df.some_column

columnName = "some_column"
df[columnName]
```

In your example, changing your reference to `df.column` to `df[column]` should resolve that issue.  However, as I mentioned in a comment, your code has other problems too.  As far as solving the task at hand, the string-indexing approach I showed at the beginning of my answer is much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, unfortunately, when I try this on the actual DataFrame it doesn't actually change anything. In the Jupyter notebook a red box appears and states that 'a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame' and says this raises a SettingWithCopy error. The documentation states that this method may return a copy of a temporary view of the DataFrame that get's thrown out afterward so it won't run.

Comment: @vino88: Then please edit your question to include a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.  (Or ask a separate question, if your new question is really about this new way of doing it and is unrelated to the code you have posted here.)