# How to make dtype converter function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, casting

I would like to make functions and pass pipe or apply method in `pandas` to avoid recursive assignment and for practice.

Here is my example dataframe.

```
A
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

And I defined my converter function,to pass pipe method.

```
def converter(df,cols,types):
df.cols=df.cols.astype(types)
return df
```

then pass to pipe method.

```
df.pipe(converter,cols=df.A,types="str")
```

but it causes an error.

> AttributeError:'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cols'

How can I avoid this kind of error?

Comment: It looks like need `[]` - `df[cols]=df[cols].astype(types)`

Comment: thank you for reply.your method work well !  I learned alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `[]` for select columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]})

print (df)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4

def converter(df,cols,types):
    df[cols]=df[cols].astype(types)
    return df

print (converter(df, 'A', float))    
     A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
```

Comment: Hard question for me. But I think if us `df.cols` it means find column with `cols` name, not with `A` name. I try find better explanation.

Comment: You can check last paragraph in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38666726/2901002)

Comment: Glad can help you. I give answer very fast, because a few months ago I had same problem as you.